# What is the maximum size of an http response?

Tags: c#, sockets, http, download-manager

i am creating an HTTP download manager, and i am using pure socket in c#.

i don't know how much HTTP data i should read in each **Network stream read** function.

if i read about 1024 byte, it's okay.

but i want to know how can i figure it out how much data is available on each read?

here is the code i am using

```
try
{
    if (port == 443)
        sslStream.Read(buffer, current_read, buffer.Length);
    else
        netStream.Read(buffer, current_read, buffer.Length);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("disconnected , can't read from stream");
    return;
}
```

the read function of stream will act when there are data in the socket. but there is no mention of buffer size. i mean should i just set the buffer length to the tcp protocol maximum packet size (64KB)?

Comment: Have you considered using the Content-Length header?  If you are trying to chunk without knowing the size of the response,  there are strategies for that.  To answer your question though, there is technically no maximum http responses size, but you would run into data type constraints if you went too high (obviously).  You may want to check out this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533988/how-much-buffer-does-networkstream-and-tcpclient-have#:~:text=2%20Answers&text=You%20can%20get%20the%20buffer,SendBufferSize%20.

Comment: well, i think you misunderstood me, or you haven't used socket yet :). i don't mean content-length header. i mean the socket read length. how much length i should read in each loop?

Comment: The size will very.   There are timers that are used to transfer data and the number of bytes will vary.   Also with TCP the routers are allow to split and merge data which will also make the received size random.  You simply read until the end.  So you need either a unique terminating character or add a byte count at beginning of message.

Comment: Keep it to between 4 and 85 kilobytes

Comment: @jdweng so how does download managers works? there should be a way to figure out how much byte is comming. unless you simple load the buffer with nulls!!!!!!!

Comment: @CaiusJard why 4 or 85 kb? is there any reference for this? i mean there is no mention about the buffer size the client should get on each read in the rfcs.https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616 
how the hell this http protocol written.

Comment: There is no technical limit to the size of a HTTP Response. Check this post.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27309773/is-there-a-limit-of-the-size-of-response-i-can-read-over-http.. P:S. Try to be nice in your responses and comments.

Comment: That's because the protocol is absolutely uninterested in implementation details like what buffer size you use to read the bytes flowing over the network, in the same way that the English dictionary is absolutely uninterested in whether you speak in a high, low, exited, bored voice etc. Protocol is all about what is said and when. I didn't say 4 or 85, I recommended that you size your buffer to somewhere between those - you're free to ignore it and choose whatever size you like. Read a byte at a time if you want

Comment: I don't wish to appear rude, but your time might be more productively spent writing at a higher level of the network stack - use an HTTP client or server that someone else already wrote. You wouldn't be asking the questions you're asking if you had sufficient background knowledge to make a good judgement call as to what you need to do, and the process of teaching you everything you'll end up asking is way out of scope for what SO is intended for. If you're desperate to learn the nuts and bolts of HTTP read the specs and also read other open source implementations

Comment: Your client is broken, as HTTP clients _must_ support chunked transfer coding, and just reading the socket like that only works if the web server sends a content-length header.  Use an HTTP library instead of making your own.

Comment: If we all had to explain in fine detail every statement we make, we'd probably never stop talking. 4kb is the default buffer size for many buffered operations; larger buffers can help with network communications that are potentially subject to higher latencies; keeping objects below 85kb helps avoid them going on the large object heap; there is no hard and fast rule for anything; spend your time doing something useful and fun - use an implementation someone else already wrote. Right now you need milk and you're making your own parts so you can make your own car so you can drive to the shops..

Comment: ..your coffee's probably gonna have grown it's own legs and walked to the shops itself sooner than it's reasonably possible to finish getting some reliable implementation of a car together..

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft thanks for your advice, but i like to have my own pure application, cause i'm a Developer!!!! so would you please check my answer to this thread and answer to my question there?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft as you mentioned the content-length for the header. the content-length is for hole data size header. i think my question is far beyond just an application or operating system. i think it depends on the routers. for example, from http server, we send 5kb of data, but this 5kb of data won't be send at a time, right? so the router will slice them into packets with some length and send these packets to the destination, and this is where my router(the destination) receives these packets and windows transfer it to my socket.i wish i could know all these in actions.

Comment: think i have to read some computer networks and access point (routers) books. but, thank you all for comments and answers. sorry if i was a jerk. i just have a little bit hurry in my life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TcpClient.Available`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.available?view=net-5.0

Gets the amount of data that has been received from the network and is available to be read.

The `Available` property is a way to determine whether data is queued for reading. If data is available, call `Read` to get the data. The available data is the total amount of data queued in the network buffer for reading. If no data is queued in the network buffer, `Available` returns `0`.

If the remote host shuts down or closes the connection, `Available` may throw a `SocketException`. If you receive a `SocketException`, use `SocketException.ErrorCode` to obtain the specific error code. After you have obtained this code, you can refer to the [Windows Sockets version 2 API error code documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2) for a detailed description of the error.

Here is the implementation of `Available` for reference (*line 345*):
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/net/system/net/Sockets/Socket.cs,345

Which is another call to operating system dll files, which I guess they are in C or C++ language.

This is the method is actually called from available in C#. `UnsafeNclNativeMethods.OSSOCK.ioctlsocket`

```cs
/// <devdoc>
///    <para>
///       Gets the amount of data pending in the network's input buffer that can be
///       read from the socket.
///    </para>
/// </devdoc>
public int Available {
    get {
        if (CleanedUp) {
            throw new ObjectDisposedException(this.GetType().FullName);
        }
 
        int argp = 0;
 
        // This may throw ObjectDisposedException.
        SocketError errorCode = UnsafeNclNativeMethods.OSSOCK.ioctlsocket(
            m_Handle,
            IoctlSocketConstants.FIONREAD,
            ref argp);
 
        GlobalLog.Print("Socket#" + ValidationHelper.HashString(this) + "::Available_get() UnsafeNclNativeMethods.OSSOCK.ioctlsocket returns errorCode:" + errorCode);
 
        //
        // if the native call fails we'll throw a SocketException
        //
        if (errorCode==SocketError.SocketError) {
            //
            // update our internal state after this socket error and throw
            //
            SocketException socketException = new SocketException();
            UpdateStatusAfterSocketError(socketException);
            if(s_LoggingEnabled)Logging.Exception(Logging.Sockets, this, "Available", socketException);
            throw socketException;
        }
 
        return argp;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP specification doesn't impose a specific size limit for posts / Get. They will usually be limited by either the web server or the programming technology used to process the form submission.